# codeigniter finding query for form

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

hey guys was hoping you could help me out..

i was asked to fix a query for someone which wasnt working. fixing the query is a rather simple problem, but i cant seem to be able to find where that query is located.i know php and mysql, but not really familiar with codeigniter framework. 
any ways, the form which results in the query being called has

action="/support/managemyaccount/profile/search"

if you could help me figure which filethe query would be in it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file should be called `support.php`, under the `application/controllers` folder.

Within that file, you should find only one class. Within that class, look for a method named `managemyaccount`. That's where your query is most likely to be.